# enable/disable onclick event with javascript with function variables

Tags: php, javascript

this is my first question to any of the forums, hope to get some useful and quick reply..

here is my php code :

```
<a href="<?php echo $sp['url']; ?>" id="bstd<?php echo $sp['Id']; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="clk('<?php echo $sp['Id']; ?>','<?php echo $_REQUEST['uid']; ?>')"><img src="images/add.jpj"></a>
```

and the following javascript function :

```
<script>
function clk(a,b){
......... the ajax code to use a,b as variables 
........
}
</script>
```

every this is working fine ...
but.
in another javascript function... i want to enable/disable the onclick of the  and href of

```
<script>
function disb(p){
if(p>5){
        av=document.getElementById(bstd); //working fine
        av.setAttribute("href", "#");  //working fine
        av.style.cursor="default";  //working fine
        av.onclick = cancel;  //not working... i want to disable the onclick.
    }else{
        av=document.getElementById(bstd);  //working fine
        av.setAttribute("href", ???);  //i want the previous code url link automatically..as it was dynamic and coming from php.
        av.style.cursor="pointer";  //working fine
        av.onclick = ???;  //i want the onclick function clk(with the dynamic php values).

    }
}
</script>
```

i know its not easy to under stand.. what i want... so here is a breif discription...

i have a image "a1" on click of this i count how many times i clicked this image... and now after this... if i clicked it more than 5 times... then only ... the onclick of  tag shoud be enabled...
otherwise on each click it should disable the onclick of  tag (i have another image which counts downwards, so i need to disable it every time, weather it is enabled or disabled)

i dont know it makes sense or not... but i want solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `Id` and `uid` to *data-** attributes, then you can define `onclick` in a way that can change without losing them. Also keep a backup of your href as such.

```
<a href="<?php echo $sp['url']; ?>"
   data-href="<?php echo $sp['url']; ?>"
   id="bstd<?php echo $sp['Id']; ?>"
   target="_blank"
   data-Id="<?php echo $sp['Id']; ?>"
   data-uid="<?php echo $sp['uid']; ?>"
   onclick="clk(this.getAttribute('data-Id'), this.getAttribute('data-uid'))"
><img src="images/add.jpj"></a>
```

then adjust your *JavaScript* for this new pattern

```
function disb(p) {
    var av = document.getElementById(bstd); // remember to use var
    if (p > 5) {
        av.href = "#"; // remove href
        av.style.cursor = "default";
        av.onclick = function () { // prevent action
            return false;
        };
    } else {
        av.href = av.getAttribute('data-href'); // restore href
        av.style.cursor = "pointer";
        av.onclick = function () { // default action
            return clk(
                this.getAttribute('data-Id'),
                this.getAttribute('data-uid')
            );
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all i  heartedly thank you for the reply... i tried it... and it works..

Comment: first of all i  heartedly thank you for the reply... it worked for me.... many many many thanks... i was struggling for this and wasted three days... i learned a new thing... thank you veryyyyyyyyyyyyy much.